# How to return user session id alongside Django rest serializer output

Tags: django, session, django-rest-framework

I'm writing a web application with Django. In one of my APIs which is using Django rest_framework, I want to return user's session ID alongside the default response. I know how to get the session ID but I don't know how to put it alongside the response(for example, in a JSON format)

This is my code:

```
class HouseInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = House
         fields = '__all__'



class HouseViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = HouseInfoSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        postcode = self.kwargs['postcode']
        print(self.request.session.session_key, "*"*10)
        return House.objects.filter(postcode=postcode)
```

Comment: How do you plan on using the session ID? It should be in the cookies of the response

Comment: @IainShelvington  Hmm. I have some security issues. I want to pass the session ID once to the client and get it in all the next requests from the client. But I don't know how to pass it alongside the rest_framework response

Comment: Why do you need it though? It doesn't sound like a great idea to be passing users' session IDs around

Comment: @IainShelvington I have a Recaptcha on the first page of my site. I want that just the real clients who have solved the Recaptcha can call the rest of my site's APIs. So after solving the Recaptcha, I should give them a token to call my APIs with that. And also each token can be called just once with an API. Fore these purposes I thought that I should pass the session ID to the client.

Comment: If the user is already authenticated then you can just use 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication' since any requests to your site will also pass the users cookies which will include their session id

Comment: @IainShelvington Can I handle the second condition with this? I don't want a user to be able to call an API with the same session id twice. Also perhaps in the future, I need to implement some other policies, for example, some users can call the API more than once but not more than three times or any other policies.